# Symfony2 - app.php returns app_dev.php

Tags: symfony

My `path/app_dev.php` works. But my app.php returns app_dev.php. Is it my `.htaccess` file?

This is my `.htaccess`. It's the default version. I've nothing changed in it:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Often when app_dev.php works and app.php doesn't, you need to clear the Symfony cache. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I did. but it redirects.

Comment: I noticed that the profiler toolbar doesn't appear with app.php and appears with app_dev.php. Conclusion: it works fine. I think the browser changes the url.